# No se como evitar que me muestre registros con campos en NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy resolviendo un problema en MySql donde tengo que intercambiar valores de una tabla de a pares. El problema lo tengo prácticamente resuelto, el tema es que me muestra los registros con el campo student NULL. Se que para omitir esos registros tendría que poner el nombre del campo where IS NOT NULL. El problema de esto es que no se como referenciar ese campo. Probé con el alias pero sale un error de sintaxis y también probé con s1.student y s2.student y tampoco sirve. Si alguien sabe como evitar que me muestre los campos con null se lo agradecería.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT s1.id, 
CASE 
    WHEN s2.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id-1 THEN s2.student
    WHEN s1.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id+1 THEN s2.student
    WHEN s1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM seat) AND s1.id%2 != 0 THEN s1.student
    ELSE NULL
END
AS student
FROM seat s1, seat s2 WHERE (aca es donde nose que poner) IS NOT NULL ORDER BY s1.id
```

---

No me sale ningun eror , el problema es que omite la instruccion `s1.student is not null`. Y la tabla de los resultados me muestra los registros con valores NULL

Tambien probe con:`WHERE s1.student IS NOT NULL AND s2.student IS NOT NULL` pero me sigue mostrando registros con el campo student en NULL.

Bueno ahi pude encontrar una **solución**, y es hacer referencia del campo con todo el bloque del case. Queda muy largo pero me funciono. Igual me gustaría saber si se puede hacer referencia a ese bloque del case de una manera mas efectiva y corta.
Así quedo el código:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT s1.id, 
CASE 
  WHEN s2.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id-1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id+1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM seat) AND s1.id%2 != 0 THEN s1.student
  ELSE NULL
END
AS student
FROM seat s1, seat s2 
WHERE (CASE 
  WHEN s2.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id-1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id+1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM seat) AND s1.id%2 != 0 THEN s1.student
  ELSE NULL
END) IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY s1.id
```

Comment: Agrega el error que obtuviste

Comment: Puedes hacer `where s1.student is not null` ¿es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: Otro tema, tienes un problema en `FROM seat s1, seat s2` te falta la clausula `on`.

Comment: Cual es el campo que queres que no sea null para mostrarlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dado que es una columna calculada y en la cláusula `WHERE` sólo podemos hacer referencia a columnas de las tablas del `FROM`, puedes envolver tu query en un `SELECT` y filtrar:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( tu_query ) tmp
  WHERE student is not null
```

Otra opción es usar la cláusula `HAVING` donde MySQL nos permite referenciar a columnas calculadas sin necesidad de un `GROUP BY`:

```
FROM seat s1, seat s2
HAVING student is not null
ORDER BY s1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que realizas un `JOIN` sin especificar la relación entre las dos tablas, además del `WHERE` donde indicarle que no muestre valores null.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.id, 
CASE 
  WHEN s2.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id-1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id+1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM seat) AND s1.id%2 != 0 THEN s1.student
  ELSE NULL
END
AS student
FROM seat s1, seat s2 
WHERE s1.id = s2.id and s1.student IS NOT NULL and s2.student IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY s1.id
```

O tambiém

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.id, 
CASE 
  WHEN s2.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id-1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id%2 = 0 AND s1.id = s2.id+1 THEN s2.student
  WHEN s1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM seat) AND s1.id%2 != 0 THEN s1.student
  ELSE NULL
END
AS student
FROM seat s1
INNER JOIN seat s2 ON s1.id = s2.id 
WHERE s1.student IS NOT NULL and s2.student IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY s1.id
```

Comment: Estas dos consultas le van a seguir mostrando resultados null, por culpa del join y las condiciones...

Comment: Un FULL JOIN (o producto punto) es válido para varios casos de uso. En este caso parece ser para ubicar asientos contíguos bajo (in)cierta distribución.